# Overflow auto doesn't work in android browser

Tags: android, css, browser

I have a page with the following directives

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

I generate dynamically table cells in the following placeholder:

```
<div id="gadget_albums" style="width:100%;overflow: auto; ">
<table>
<tr id="albums_t"></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

It works perfectly on iOS devices, but for some reason no horizontal scrolling on Android. What could be a reason?

From this side I see like people try use

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

but no luck either. Any solution?

Comment: I'm testing my app with a Samsung Tab 3 with Android 4.1.2, and even when it's supposed to have native support for `overflow: auto`, Overthrow is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

The `overflow: auto` property for a `<div>` is not yet available in Android.
You'll have to find a work around for this. I mean using the combination of JavaScript, css, HTML you can achieve this.

Check [this](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=147) out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found nice [solution](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/), it works like a charm.