# not able to scroll vertically in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have created one div container in which i am populating multiple divs dynamically , but in my handset i am not able to scroll it.
i am using `jQuery Mobile` in `android 2.2.X`

here is the code inside a `content` 
HTML

```
<div id="myContainer">




</div>
```

CSS

```
 #myContainer{

    width: auto;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;

}
```

dynamic instertion

```
 $("#myContainer").append("<div>"+emp.Name+"</div>");
```

Comment: are you using iphone or ipad version < IOS 6.0 ?

Comment: i am using android 2.2.X

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493724/overflow-auto-doesnt-in-android-browser

Comment: some versions on IOS doesn't support scrolling vertically using jquery mobile .. this link may help you
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/pages/touchoverflow.html

Comment: none of the above are aworking