# Below android 2.3.4 overflow:auto not working

Tags: android, css, overflow, android-browser, mobile-browser

Below android 2.3.4 overflow:auto not working in my android mobile browser

Example:

> `<div style="overflow:auto; height:200px"> Test data </div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given in this answer

[Overflow auto doesn't work in android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493724/overflow-auto-doesnt-in-android-browser)

Also check [this](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/)